# Как изменить один элемент GridView?

Tags: android

как в этом примере, на клик по элементу GridView поменять его содержимое?

например `Чили(выбран)`

http://metanit.com/java/android/5.5.php

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> 

    <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

    String[] countries = { "Бразилия", "Аргентина", "Чили", "Колумбия", "Уругвай", "Парагвай"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // получаем элемент ListView
        GridView countriesList = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

        // создаем адаптер
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countries);
        countriesList.setAdapter(adapter);

        OnItemClickListener itemListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Вы выбрали "
                            + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        countriesList.setOnItemClickListener(itemListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: колбэк `onItemClick()` вторым параметром возвращает вью по которому кликнули (View v). Вы можете использовать все доступные для класса `View` методы для его изменения.

Comment: @pavlofff, хотелось обновить `модель`  в данном случае `String[] countries` и сказать GridView обновиться самостоятельно, такое возможно?

Comment: Все адаптеры имеют метод `notifyDataSetChanged()`,который указывет адаптеру обновить айтемы после изменения в моделях

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть мнение, что напрямую работать со списком String из-за их immutability не очень правильно, возможно стоит завернуть их в объект модели. Тогда будет работать вот такой вариант https://stackoverflow.com/a/30711959/5892568

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

            String beforeName = itemListAdapter.getItem(position).getItemName().toString();

            String changedName = beforeName.concat("(chosen)");
            itemListAdapter.getItem(position).setItemName(changedName);
            itemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

Для GridView надо видимо еще и изменить сам список:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

            String beforeName = itemListAdapter.getItem(position);

            String changedName = beforeName..getItemName().toString().concat("(chosen)");

            itemListAdapter.remove(beforeName);
            itemListAdapter.insert(new Item(changedName), position);

            itemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

Comment: реализовал код из этого примера:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711517/how-to-change-the-contents-of-listview-on-item-click/30711959#30711959,
заменил ListView на GridView, но почемуто Adapter обновляется, а GridView не перерисовывается

Comment: For an ArrayAdapter, notifyDataSetChanged only works if you use the add(), insert(), remove(), and clear() on the Adapte http://stackoverflow.com/a/5092426/5892568